# Check if a git branch is properly rebased

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm looking to create a server hook that ensure a branch is properly rebased and look like this clean graph :

```
*   883ffd1 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, composer/master, master) Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\  
| * 1062849 ...
|/  
*   becc0d5 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\  
| * 36abc00 ...
| * 6c2462a ...
| * c4c53a7 ...
|/  
*   021f4c4 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\  
| * cce9877 ...
|/  
*   2d3eed0 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\  
| * a6c1c5c ...
|/  
*   b1e9311 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
```

And should prevent this kind of graph :

```
*   2c9fad0 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\  
| * 7bdf6c9 commit
| *   7de8146 Merge branch 'FEATURE-functional-tests' of ssh://... into FEATURE-functional-tests
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 8f8f3fb commit
* | f5a16e4 ...
* | c59a5c7 ...
* |   0e9979a Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\ \  
| * | 697bb30 ...
|/ /  
* |   315eeb6 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\ \  
| * | 3035d50 ...
* | |   70515bb Merge branch '...' into 'master'
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
| * | 4032719 ...
* | |   35d4a19 Merge branch '...' into 'master'
```

How can I check something like that?